# elapsed days between specific days per group

Tags: python, pandas

From the dataframe bellow, I would like to calculate the number of days until each event per year

```
lst = [['2011-02-01',''],
        ['2011-02-02',''],
        ['2011-02-03',''],
        ['2011-02-04','event1'],
        ['2011-02-05',''],
        ['2011-02-06','event_2'],
        ['2012-02-01',''],
        ['2012-02-02',''],
        ['2012-02-03',''],
        ['2012-02-04',''],
        ['2012-02-05','event_1'],
        ['2012-02-06','event_2']]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['date','event'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

Desired output would be something like bellow:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np


df=df.assign(days_until_event_1=None, days_until_event_2=None)

epoch_factor=24*60*60*10**9

for y in df["year"].unique():
    dfel=df.loc[df["year"].eq(y)]
    dfel=dfel.iloc[::-1]
    dfel["days_until_event_1"]=np.where(dfel["event"].eq("event_1"), dfel["date"].astype(str), None)
    dfel["days_until_event_1"]=pd.to_datetime(dfel["days_until_event_1"].ffill().bfill())-dfel["date"]
    dfel["days_until_event_2"]=np.where(dfel["event"].eq("event_2"), dfel["date"].astype(str), None)
    dfel["days_until_event_2"]=pd.to_datetime(dfel["days_until_event_2"].ffill().bfill())-dfel["date"]
    df.loc[df["year"].eq(y), ["days_until_event_1", "days_until_event_2"]]=dfel[["days_until_event_1", "days_until_event_2"]].div(epoch_factor)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df.iloc[:, -2:]

    days_until_event_1  days_until_event_2
0                    3                   5
1                    2                   4
2                    1                   3
3                    0                   2
4                   -1                   1
5                   -2                   0
6                    4                   5
7                    3                   4
8                    2                   3
9                    1                   2
10                   0                   1
11                  -1                   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [['2011-02-01',''],
        ['2011-02-02',''],
        ['2011-02-03',''],
        ['2011-02-04','event_1'],
        ['2011-02-05',''],
        ['2011-02-06','event_2'],
        ['2012-02-01',''],
        ['2012-02-02',''],
        ['2012-02-03',''],
        ['2012-02-04',''],
        ['2012-02-05','event_1'],
        ['2012-02-06','event_2']]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['date','event'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year


#### utility functions ####

def count_down(event, code):
    results = []
    i = -1
    partial = []
    for e in np.asarray(event):
        if e == code:
            partial.append(i+1)
            results.extend(partial[::-1])
            partial = []
            i = -1
        else:
            i += 1
            partial.append(i)
    results.extend(partial[::-1])
    return results

def reverse_count_down(event, code):
    results = []
    i = 0
    partial = []
    for e in np.asarray(event):
        if e == code:
            partial.append(i+1)
            results.extend(partial)
            partial = []
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
            partial.append(i)
    results.extend(partial)
    return results


df['days_until_event1'] = count_down(df.event, 'event_1')
df['days_until_event2'] = count_down(df.event, 'event_2')

# insert nevative values
c_down = np.asarray(reverse_count_down(df.event, 'event_1'))
substitute = np.where(df.days_until_event1>=df.days_until_event2)[0]
df.loc[substitute, 'days_until_event1'] = -c_down[substitute]
df
```

[image]